# How to install the Plugins through commands/manually in SonarQube Container?

Tags: docker, sonarqube

I have deployed a SonarQube container using a sonarqube:7.1 docker image. The container is running and able to access the SonarQube UI. but unable to creating quality profiles and downloading plugins. Login into Sonarqube container and extensions/downloads folder doesn't have any plugins. Getting version compatibility issues while downloading plugins from the marketplace.

So, Please correct me if my question is meaningless, Is there any way to install plugins manually inside the container?

Could anyone help me to resolve this issue? Any suggestible links are also more helpful to me...